# Android java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()

Tags: java, android, synchronization, notify

I define a global static object as a synchronization lock.

```
public static Object ConfirmationSynObj = new Object();
```

The following function is what I wrote, but it throw a IllegalMonitorStateException.

```
       synchronized (Config.ConfirmationSynObj) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //this is a http request
                    appSignInfo = getAPKSignature(context, pkinfo.packageName);
                    Config.ConfirmationSynObj.notify();
                }
            }).start();
            try {
                Config.ConfirmationSynObj.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (appSignInfo == null) {
                return ret;
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know how to lock an object or a function in order to prevent the concurrency?

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common replacement for `wait`/`notify` is `CountDownLatch`. (From `java.util.concurrent` as well but working kind of inverse of `Semaphore` - see answer by Tom)

You initialize it to the amount of steps required, threads that have finished count down and some other place waits for the countdown to reach 0.

```
void doFoo() {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //this is a http request
            appSignInfo = getAPKSignature(context, pkinfo.packageName);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }).start();
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (appSignInfo == null) {
        return ret;
    }
}
```

But the code you wrote there can be simplified to

```
void doFoo() {
    return getAPKSignature(context, pkinfo.packageName);
}
```

You start a second thread to do something and all you do in that time is to wait. If there is nothing to do while that task is running don't create an extra thread. The result is the same.

If you try to do a HTTP request outside of the UI thread because you get that `NetworkOnMainThreadExcpeption`, you have to do it differently. While Android won't detect your code as long time blocking code it still is. Use an AsyncTask for example.

Comment: @user924 What's the point of your comment? Yes they are different but a latch will fulfill a subset of wait/notify's cases.

Answer (score 5):

@Kayaman speaks correctly, as far as I can tell, however if I may humbly suggest: `java.util.concurrent` can save you lots of time!

What I'd use there is a [semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

From the docs: "Each acquire() blocks if necessary until a permit is available, and then takes it.".

But there are other choices too- I strongly recommend using this where possible, as you should avoid lots of pit falls as in your case.

```
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //this is a http request
                appSignInfo = getAPKSignature(context, pkinfo.packageName);
                semaphore.release();
            }
        }).start();
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
```

Above thread is not owning lock on `ConfirmationSynObj` object hence throwing `IllegalMonitorStateException`

Use one more synchronized block inside `run` method

```
           @Override
            public void run() {
            synchronized (Config.ConfirmationSynObj) {
                //this is a http request
                appSignInfo = getAPKSignature(context, pkinfo.packageName);
                Config.ConfirmationSynObj.notify();
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be creating and starting the thread in the synchronized block, but when the thread comes to `Config.ConfirmationSynObj.notify();` you'll notice that there's no synchronization.

You'll need to add a synchronized block inside run().