# Error when running, recording audio

Tags: android, multithreading, audio-recording

Whenever I try running this app in the emulator I get this error:

```
09-11 05:34:08.580      859-859/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 10% free 3448K/3792K, paused 28ms, total 29ms
09-11 05:34:08.650      859-859/com.spookyapps.lollatone I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 15.450MB for 12381028-byte allocation
09-11 05:34:08.680      859-868/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 15536K/15884K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
09-11 05:34:09.410      859-859/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 15760K/16108K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
09-11 05:34:09.430      859-859/com.spookyapps.lollatone I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 18.084MB for 2536936-byte allocation
09-11 05:34:09.470      859-868/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 18237K/18588K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
09-11 05:34:09.640      859-859/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-11 05:34:09.640      859-859/com.spookyapps.lollatone W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a19ba8)
09-11 05:34:09.650      859-872/com.spookyapps.lollatone W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a19ba8)
09-11 05:34:09.650      859-872/com.spookyapps.lollatone I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 859 SIG: 9
```

here is my main activity

```
package com.spookyapps.lollatone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Sounds mSound = new Sounds();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mSound.record();
            }
        });
        thread.start();


        try {
            wait(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("Record", "wait failed");
        }

        //Sounds.mIsRecording = false;

        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e("Thread", "Join failed");
        }

        mSound.play();
        finish();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

the sound class

```
package com.spookyapps.lollatone;

import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Created by abc on 9/7/2014.
 */
public class Sounds {
    public boolean mIsRecording = false;

    public void record() {
        int frequency = 11025;
        int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
        int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/reverseme.pcm");

        //change later to create new file like "_1" "_2" etc based on constant
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }

        //create the new file
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create" + file.toString());
        }

        try {
            // Create a DataOutputStream to write the audio data into the saved file
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

            // Create a new AudioRecord object to record the audio
            int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
            AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    frequency, channelConfiguration,
                    audioEncoding, bufferSize);

            short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize];
            audioRecord.startRecording();
            mIsRecording = true;

            while (mIsRecording) {
                int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                    dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);
                }
            }

            audioRecord.stop();
            mIsRecording = false;
            dos.close();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
        }

    }

    public void play() {
        // get the file to play back
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/reverseme.pcm");
        //Get the length of the audio stored in the file (16 bit so 2 bytes per short)
        //and create a short array to store the recorded audio
        int musicLength = (int) (file.length());
        short[] music = new short[musicLength];

        try {
            //Create a DataInputStream to read the audio data back from the saved file
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

            //Read the file into the music array
            int i = 0;
            while (dis.available() > 0) {
                music[musicLength - 1 - i] = dis.readShort();
                i++;
            }

            // close the input streams
            dis.close();


            // Create a new AudioTrack object using the same parameters as the AudioRecord
            // object used to create the file

            AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    musicLength,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            // Start playback
            audioTrack.play();

            //Write the music buffer to the AudioTrack object
            audioTrack.write(music, 0, musicLength);

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("AudioTrack", "Playback Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to automatically try recording audio and then then playing it back once the app starts but the app never starts at all and I just get those messages in the logcat

EDIT: new errors:

09-11 05:53:07.631    1143-1143/com.spookyapps.lollatone E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: com.spookyapps.lollatone, PID: 1143
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spookyapps.lollatone/com.spookyapps.lollatone.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
        at com.spookyapps.lollatone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: there must be more in the logcat, this GC_ALLOC messages have nothing do do with the shut down. Is this really all You get?

Comment: and I think You should also post important part of Your Sounds class

Comment: Sorry, third comment :)...why You are finishing the activity? You have no chance to play the sound if You directly finishing the activity, remove finish(); If You want to finish the activity when the Sound is over, You have to do it in another way..

Comment: I added the sound class above. Also I removed the finish() and now get these errors edited in above

Comment: I think what´s causing this problem has something to do with Your Thread/wait/notify. But that´s a thing that I have not used until now and I have no IDE here to test something, so I can´t give You the wright answer. But maybe this link will help You: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811794/android-java-lang-illegalmonitorstateexception-object-not-locked-by-thread-befo

Answer (score 0):

First exit from eclipse

Go to directory "C:\Users\Admin.android" and delete avd , cache folder, & adbkey.pub.

then restart the eclipse make new avd and then run your activity/application.

it definitely run's.

Comment: Using androidStudio. But I did what you said and still get this: 09-11 15:46:50.230    1049-1049/com.spookyapps.lollatone D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-11 15:46:50.230    1049-1049/com.spookyapps.lollatone W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a87ba8)
09-11 15:46:50.240    1049-1062/com.spookyapps.lollatone W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a87ba8)